# How to construct IQueryable query using Linq when I just need count without reading all documents in Document-Db database?

Tags: c#, linq, azure, azure-cosmosdb, iqueryable

I need the number of documents stored in a collection in my Azure Cosmos Db database. How can I get the count using LINQ query on the `IQueryable` object?

```
docDbClient.CreateDocumentQuery<TResult>().Count()
```

If I do above, I am unable to follow it up with `.AsDocumentQuery()` method.

Comment: `Count` returns a single integer - why would you want to *follow* it by something that wants to work with a "group" of items?

Comment: One more thing....DocumentDB API natively supports `Count` queries. You should try using that instead of doing the count this way.

Comment: So, I have to construct the SQL statement myself in this case, instead of using the LINQ provider?

Comment: Your query should already do precisely what you want - get a count without retrieving anything else.

Comment: But to use this IOrderedQueryable with Document-DB, I must call the AsDocumentQuery(), right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my async implementation (use Count, for the sync version):

```
var count = await DocumentClient.
            CreateDocumentQuery<T>(CreateCollectionUri(), CreateFeedOptions()).
            Where(predicate).
            CountAsync();
```

where predicate is `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`

Answer (score 3):

Another way to acheive that is:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Linq; // required for CountAsync()
//...
cosmosClient
    .GetContainer(databaseName, containerName)
    .GetItemLinqQueryable<MyRecord>(true)
    .Where(r => r.Name == "John")
    .Where(r => r.Status == MyRecordStatus.Approved)
    .CountAsync()
```

Comment: is there any specific reason why you are allowing synchronous execution (`.GetItemLinqQueryable<MyRecord>(true)`)?

Comment: Yes, I can not recall it now, but I tested that and did not work for some reason. Synchronous execution was used on purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use the following code to count the number of documents in your collection.

```
client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(EndpointUri), PrimaryKey);

IQueryable<int> total = client.CreateDocumentQuery<int>(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("testdb", "testcoll"), "SELECT Value count(1) FROM c", new FeedOptions() { EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true });

Console.WriteLine("total: " + total.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault());
```

**Query result:**

[image]

If you capture the request (using fiddler etc), you will find that the client sdk send the same query `{"query":"SELECT VALUE [{\"item\": Count(1)}]\r\nFROM root"}` to the server when you execute your code `docDbClient.CreateDocumentQuery<TResult>().Count()`.